# Record not delete in cake php

Tags: php, cakephp-1.3, cakephp

In cake php ,

```
if ($this->BanquetBillMaster->BanquetOtherBillMaster->del($this->data['BanquetOtherBillMaster']['id'])
 {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Menu type deleted successfully !', true));
    $this->redirect(array('action'=>'add_other_items'));            
   exit();
 }
```

same code use in another controller it works, but here its not working

anyone help me...

Comment: del() has been depreciated and removed a long time ago, you should be using delete()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have not added The required model in uses.Please check that first..

var $uses = array('Patient','User','StaticPage','Latestupdate','Member','Agent');

Comment: You don't add controllers in `uses` you add models. Even then, you should really be using automatic association. Please revise your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're accessing the model from a controller, the same code may work in one controller, but not another.

For example

```
$this->BanquetBillMaster->BanquetOtherBillMaster->del()
```

This may work in your `BanquetBillMasterController()` but not in your `BanquetOtherBillMasterController()` (*This depends on how you have your app set up, but generally this holds true.*). This is because of the associations CakePHP builds up.

So, before calling `$this->BanquetBillMaster->BanquetOtherBillMaster` make sure those models are available in the controllers you call.

Comment: thanx, both the model have $hasMany relation